# Create array from PHP SQL query and pass it to ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to get my results from a SQL query into an array in javascript. I'm trying the following:

PHP:

```
$query = mysqli_query($connection, "select a, b, c from table"); 

$result_a = array();
$result_b = array();
$result_c = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
$result_a[] = $row['a'];
$result_b[] = $row['b'];
$result_c[] = $row['c'];
}
echo json_encode(array('a'=>$result_a,'b'=>$result_b, 'c'=>$result_c ));
```

javascript:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "http://mywebsite.com/data.php",
        data: dataString3,
        cache: false,
        error: function(){},
        success: function(data){
            alert (data.a);
            alert (data.b);
            alert (data.c);
            },
            });
        return false;
```

The PHP arrays have the data I'm looking for but the alerts in javascript are undefined. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sending the correct `Content-Type: application/json` header in your PHP script? If not, the `$.ajax()` request will not automatically unserialize the data.

Comment: When I add `header ("Content-Type: application/json");` to my php script the ajax error function is called? As soon as I remove it, the ajax success () is called... still undefined arrays. Any ideas?

Comment: Make sure you set that header before anything is written to the page. If that still doesn't work you'll probably have to use your browser's developer tools to debug the issue (look at the Network details and see what is actually being sent in the ajax call).

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you echo data in json format `json_encode(array('a'=>$result_a,'b'=>$result_b, 'c'=>$result_c ));`

So if you want to use the json as an object directly in the ajax success function, you need tell the ajax call "You are expecting a json object coming bakc!";
So you should modified js code to this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://mywebsite.com/data.php",
    data: dataString3,
    cache: false,
    dataType : "json", // <------here, auto parse json for you
    error: function(){},
    success: function(data){
          alert (data.a);
          alert (data.b);
          alert (data.c);
    }
});
```

Or in the success function, manually parse json before use;

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://mywebsite.com/data.php",
        data: dataString3,
        cache: false
        error: function(){},
        success: function(data){
              var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data); // <---- here, manual parse
              alert (obj.a);
              alert (obj.b);
              alert (obj.c);
        }
    });
```